# A good resource to learn Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to learn Action script 3 what is a good resource to learn it?

Comment: Do you know AS2 or Javascript?

Comment: I'm guessing a good book or a search engine.

Comment: I only know PHP and some Ruby on Rails 3 and yes a good book suggestion would be nice!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=as3+resources

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Sites

http://www.paultrani.com/blog/

Flash Mobile

http://www.flashmobileblog.com/

---

### Videos

Presented by the great Lee Brimlow

http://www.gotoandlearn.com/

---

### Books

Two books I know are good (in my opinion)

**Learning Actionscript 3**
 Very concise book:

[http://www.amazon.com/Learning-ActionScript-3-0-Beginners-Guide/dp/059652787X/ref=pd_bbs_sr_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1208191030&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059652787X)

**ActionScript 3.0 Cookbook** 
My favourite

http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596526955

Comment: thank you i will check out all these resources.

Answer (score 3):

Since ActionScript wasn't my first language, I can't give the same opinions as to which are great resources as someone just starting out with programming could.

However, I have a few sites bookmarked which I have heard great things about from other beginners to AS3:

- [AS3 101](http://active.tutsplus.com/sessions/as3-101/) - by ActiveTuts
- [Flash and ActionScript 911](http://www.untoldentertainment.com/blog/flash-and-actionscript-911) - by Untold Entertainment
- [Learn to create an AS3 avoider game from scratch](http://gamedev.michaeljameswilliams.com/as3-avoider-game-tutorial-base/) - by Michal James Williams

Plus, for once you get better at AS3, a list of the top mistakes you **will** definitely make (these are the types of questions that are asked on the Kirupa forums nearly every day!)

- [6 common ActionScript mistakes made by beginners](http://www.ahrooga.com/entry/6-common-actionscript-3-mistakes-made-by-beginners/)

Finally, if you need a forum to belong to and a place to ask questions when you get stuck, I would really recommend the Kirupa fourms. It is a fantastic and very friendly community. :)

Comment: I've never figured out how to navigate Kirupa and I've never had the ability to say the name to well - Always say 'kipura... kupur...' - Nice links +1.

Answer (score 0):

The official livedocs are great:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html?filter_flashplayer=10.2#top

Just pick a class that sounds interesting, and there should be examples for the important methods.